# Picture overlaps the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera, navigation-drawer

I have picture (a hat) on the front camera preview (in Fragment), so you can try the hat on before buying. But the problem is that when in this preview I am trying to open Navigation Drawer my hat overlaps this Drawer and the front camera is below the Navigation Drawer. How can I make the picture (hat) be below the Navigation Drawer?

MirrorFragment.java:

```
public class MirrorFragment extends Fragment implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private Camera camera = null;

    private SurfaceHolder cameraSurfaceHolder = null;
    private boolean previewing = false;
    private static int wid = 0, hgt = 0;
    private View cameraViewControl;
    private Button btnCapture;
    private Activity activity;

    public MirrorFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SurfaceView cameraSurfaceView;
        Display display;


        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mirror, container, false);
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        int toolbarHeight = ((MainActivity) activity).getToolbar().getHeight();


        display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        wid = display.getWidth();
        hgt = display.getHeight();


        activity.getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        cameraSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.cameraSurfaceViewFragment);
        cameraSurfaceHolder = cameraSurfaceView.getHolder();

        cameraSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        cameraSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);



        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        cameraViewControl = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cambutton, null);

        btnCapture = (Button) cameraViewControl.findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

        setMarginTopForHat(toolbarHeight);


        activity.addContentView(cameraViewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        return view;
    }




    public void setMarginTopForHat(int height) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) btnCapture.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.setMargins(0, height + 30, 0, 0);
        btnCapture.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }    


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {
            camera = Camera.open(1);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Device camera is not working properly, please try after sometime.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        ((ViewGroup) cameraViewControl.getParent()).removeView(cameraViewControl);
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

fragment_mirror.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/cameraSurfaceViewFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hat `View` is appearing over the drawer because you're using the Activity's `addContentView()` method, which is adding it as the last child in the Activity's content `ViewGroup`, making it draw on top of the rest of its contents. If the `ViewGroup` that you're loading the `MirrorFragment` into is a `FrameLayout`, you could just add it to that instead. However, the probably preferable solution is to add it directly to the `fragment_mirror` layout, either programmatically, or in the layout XML.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Should I change the method `addContentView()` to other method? Because I was trying to put into `addContentView()` different parameters (such as `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mirror, container, false);` and it didn't work.

Comment: You don't want to use `addContentView()`, since that's what's causing the hat View to appear over everything else. You want to use the `addView()` method of whichever ViewGroup you decide to add the hat View to. I'd suggest adding it directly to `view` before you return that in `onCreateView()`. You might need to change the `fragment_mirror` layout, though, depending on what type of ViewGroup it has as its root. If you want to post that layout, I can be more specific.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the layout of MirrorFragment. Please take a look.

Comment: OK, it looks like you're mostly good to go. Just change the `activity.addContentView()` line to `((RelativeLayout) view).addView(cameraViewControl, layoutParamsControl);`. (I'm assuming your hat View is in `cameraViewControl`.)